# How to drag & drop lots of files without taxing system resources?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, drag-and-drop

One of the features that the program that I'm working on is the ability to drag objects from its main window and drop them onto Windows Explorer as files.

To do this, we override `COleDataSource::OnRenderGlobalData()` and, when the format is `CF_HDROP`, we save each object as a file. This works fine when the number of objects is small.

However, as we're now working on supporting enterprise level amounts of objects, we're seeing big delays, sometimes leading to hangs or eventual crashes, when the user tries to drag a lot of objects from our application into Windows Explorer.

My guess is that this is happening because `OnRenderGlobalData()` is being called quite a number of times, and of course, each time it has to loop through the objects that are being dragged and save them as files.

I was looking into the idea of overriding `OnRenderFileData()`, but the problem with that is that it only deals with one file at a time.

Is there any way that I can speed up our application when the user tries to drag a lot of objects onto Windows Explorer, preferably by moving the save loop to a place where it can be executed only once when the actual drop takes place?

Comment: What are the source objects?  Are they backed by a file to begin with? How does the performance of your drag&drop compare to dragging the equivalent number of objects from an Outlook folder to the desktop? I have some drag&drop code to reference for an answer, but want to know more about what the data is.

Comment: @selbie: The source objects are items in a vertical market application and are not backed up by files to begin with. The performance appears to be noticeably faster when compared with dragging an equivalent number of objects from an Outlook folder. (I tested with 60 e-mails vs. 60 of our objects.) The problems come when the user tries to drag a large number of these objects (several hundred or more, which is common on large sites, such as university campuses, large buildings, etc.) into Windows explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating files, drag virtual data that is generated at drop time. Offer CFSTR_FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR and CFSTR_FILECONTENTS. [Here's an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/03/31/8344798.aspx).

Comment: Please explain this in some more detail.  How can 'virtual data', whatever that is, be dropped onto windows explorer and create a file that has not previously been created by the application that is the source of the data?

Comment: The technique does look interesting.  Here is a codeproject article, very MFC orientated, that explains some more http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/ExplorerDelayDrop.aspx

Comment: OK, this is the correct answer.  The 'virtual file' when it is dropped into the destination folder, does a remote procedure call from windows explorer to the source application OnRenderFileData() method AFTER the drop is completed.  Now the source application can take as long as it likes, showing progress indications, etc to write the file(s).  There is no create temporary files when the drag starts.  The codeproject article is the place to start from - the code supplied there compiles and runs cleanly.

Comment: This sounds like it could be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  My 'solution' is not very clever.  I offer drag'n'drop as a convenience for a small number of objects.  If the use has selected more than the number of objects that can be well handled, drag'n'drop is disabled and instead the user must select the destination from a folder browser dialog.  When the destination is selected, the objects are written as files there, with a progress indicator.