# Drag & Drop Virtual files from wxWidgets application to windows explorer

Tags: wxwidgets

I need to drag and drop 'virtual files' from a wxWidgets application to windows explorer.  This [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/tips/ExplorerDelayDrop.aspx) is an excellent description and demonstration of how to do in MFC.  It is not at all clear to me how to use the wxWidgets classes (  wxDataObject, wxTextDataObject, wxDropSource, wxDropTarget, wxTextDropTarget, wxFileDropTarget ) to do the same thing.  Can anyone give me some hints on how to proceed?

Motivation:  I need to drag and drop files that are located on a remote device.  Pulling them from the device and reformatting them as required takes many seconds - minutes if many files are selected.  The delay makes the drag and drop completely unusable if the files are downloaded and reformatted when the drag starts but before the drop.  Using a virtual file allows the drop to be completed, and only then are the files copied - this makes the drag'n'drop smooth and familiar to the user.

Here is a [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868245/how-to-drag-drop-lots-of-files-without-taxing-system-resources) - but it is for MFC and I need a wxWidgets solution.

So, I tried following the codeproject example and specializing COleDataSource.  However, when I include afxole.h the compiler complains

```
Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
```

This does not look hopeful.

My thought now is I am going to have to use IDataObject.  Does that seem reasonable?  Can someone point me to a gentle introduction to using this?